# Who knows how to connect the "Ulkit 3" (https://getuikit.com/) to "Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, frontend, vuejs2, vue.js

Who knows how to connect the "Ulkit 3" (https://getuikit.com/) to "Vue.js 2". I can't find some guides in the internet for this theme. I need exactly UIkit 3 version. I don't need the VUIKIT because it based on UIkit 2, not in UIkit 3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation and website for UIKit are actually using Vue and UIKit.  You might want to check out the Github repo to get some pointers (https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#uikit-and-reactive-javascript-frameworks) and then if you have a specific problem, you can ask a new question on Stackoverflow with some sample code showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case the original asker is still looking, VUIKIT has a branch implementing UIKit 3:

https://github.com/vuikit/vuikit/tree/next

It is actively developed (as of 14/11/2017) and nearly feature complete.